# HTML clicking on a div and then highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created this using flex box

[image]

```css
.itemy:hover {
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}
```

```html
<div class="drinkDisplay">
  <?php
    if($arr5!=="Drinks" && $arr5!=="Add Ons" && $arr5!=="A la carte" && $arr5!=="Dessesrts"){
      for($i=0;$i<$numrowsDrinks;$i++){
        echo "<div id='$drinkId[$i]' class='itemy'> 
                  <img src= $drinkImage[$i] alt = $drinkName[$i]>                       <div class='textcontainer'><p>$drinkName[$i]<br>PHP +$drinkPrice[$i]</p></div></div>";
                    }

                }
              ?>
</div>
```

right now when its hovered it will highlight the item which is good. But i would like that when i click the div(itemy) it will retain that highlight. i have tried the following js code but it would not retain the highlight after the click.(shown below)

```js
var addclass = 'color';
var $cols = $('.itemy').click(function() {
  $cols.removeClass(addclass);
  $(this).addClass(addclass);
});
```

```css
.color {
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}
```

i would also like to access the data of the highlighted div later on when fore say the user clicks a button i would like to get the let us say the id of the selected div.

thank you very much for your help

Comment: The code you've included in your question works as you expect. It will un-highlight the other elements, and the clicked element will have the background color.

Comment: Except the fact that you are not using best practices when declaring variables :  variable name notation ( no camel case and confusing name ) , plus using `var` instead of `let` or `const` . ( `const` should be used here ). Everything works. Try writing a more specific selector like `.drinkDisplay .itemy.color { } `

Comment: @MihaiT Neither of the things you described are "wrong".

Comment: @TylerRoper well..not wrong wrong but not using best practices :)

Comment: @TylerRoper yes the highlight is working as it should be . it is just that i would like(on top of the already placed highligh) to have a click highlight that persist until i click another item.

Comment: @Jack Correct. The code you have in your question does exactly that. [**See here**](https://jsfiddle.net/6n7m8ryv/) - I've literally copy+pasted your snippet, and it works. Essentially, the issue with your code is *not present in your question*, so we can only "guess" as to what might be wrong. Please edit your question to include a **full** reproduction of the issue (including HTML and CSS).

Comment: surely you just need to bind a click event something to something and then get all your selected items using `$('.itemy.color')`?  Also what is not working about your click event to add and remove the colour class?  *to no avail* doesn't explain what the problem is - does it add the class, does it not remove it - what is the exact nature of the problem?

Comment: Oh, a shot in the dark here. Do you have jQuery included ?

Comment: Is this code at the end of your `<body>`, or in the `<head>`? And, if in the `<head>`, is it inside of a `$(document).ready( ... )` ? I'm voting to close this question as it's just devolving into a guessing game. Please considering adding a [**Minimal, complete, verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TylerRoper im sorry, i am having problem with the click, after the click the highlight doesnt remain.

Comment: @MihaiT yes here is the line. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @TylerRoper it is around in the middle of the body, there are headers and footers in the body.

Comment: @Jack The middle of the body is a very strange place to have any JS. Is it *before* your `itemy` elements? If this code is on the page before your `itemy` elements and is not waiting for the page to load, you're trying to attach click events to elements that don't yet exist. The code to look for the `itemy` elements will run before the `itemy` elements are on the page.

Comment: @Jack i am fairly sure the problem is with the CSS selector. try using `.itemy.color {..}` or `.drinkDisplay .itemy.color {...}`. Also, try inspecting the html code and tell us if the `color` class is added when clicking on the items

Comment: Look your example online working without any problem http://jsfiddle.net/2reycn3a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone having patience on me.

```js
$(".itemy").on("click", function() {
      $(".itemy").css("background-color","");
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

Here is the code that worked for me :) i can get it to click now thank you ! :)

this code still has a little problem that it it lets you highlight multiple items, and it must only be one. I will continue to look the answer.

edit: got it fully working now with the code above;

Answer (score 3):

Use two classes for the coloring - one for the onHover event, let's say "hovered" and the second for long term selection, for example "selected".

When hovering occurs remove the `hovered` class from all of the buttons and add it to the one that is being hovered, just like you do. When user clicks, add the `selected` class instead, so that the hovering doesn't interfere with selection.

```
var hoverClass = "hovered";
var selectionClass = "selected";
//code for hover
$('.itemy').hover( function() {
    $('.itemy').removeClass(hoverClass);
    $(this).addClass(hoverClass);
});
//code for clicking if you want to be able to select multiple items
$('.itemy').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass(selectionClass);
});
//code for clicking if you want to be able to select only a single item
$('.itemy').click( function() {
    $('.itemy').removeClass(selectionClass);
    $(this).addClass(selectionClass);
});
```

Set CSS for both classes as you please. If you want it the same, you can even set the same CSS for multiple selectors like this:

```
.hovered, .selected {
    //...your style here
}
```

Comment: While I won't downvote it, I can't help but feel like any answers to this question are just going to be shot-in-the-dark guesses because the original question is off topic. Answering off-topic questions is generally [grounds for a downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions).

Comment: You're completely right @Tyler Cooper. What I was trying to say is that he shoud differentiate between the selected and hovered states in general. It's just a nudge in a direction. As you said it's hard to provide a definite or optimal answer because of the manner of the question. I appreciate you considered it.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have your entire CSS file to verify, the `.color` class likely doesn't have a **high enough specificity** to overide the original `.itemy` styling.

Try changing your `.color` class declaration to be more specific like so...

```
.itemy.color {
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}
```

This requires the element to be both `itemy` and `color` so it is more specific. This isn't fully supported in older browsers, but there are other ways of increasing the specificity which are more backward compatible (ig. specifiying parent elements like `.grandparent .parent .color`)

Answer (score 1):

your listener "click" **must be** into the **document ready** function to work ([see details](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp)).

Your CSS specific properties can work with `.color` or `.itemy:hover`.

At the end of the Javascript follow snippet, I added a function to get the selected item ID :) Hope it'll help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var addclass = 'color';
  var $cols = $('.itemy').click(function() {
    $cols.removeClass(addclass);
    $(this).addClass(addclass);
  });
});

function getSelectedItemId() {
  var id = $('.color').attr("id");
  $('.result').html(id);
}
```

```css
.color,
.itemy:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drinkDisplay">
<div onclick="javascript:getSelectedItemId();">click here to get id</div>
<div class="result"></div>
  <div id='1' class='itemy'>
    <div class='textcontainer'>
      <p>Test 1<br>example 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='2' class='itemy'>
    <div class='textcontainer'>
      <p>Test 1<br>example 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='3' class='itemy'>
    <div class='textcontainer'>
      <p>Test 1<br>example 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='4' class='itemy'>
    <div class='textcontainer'>
      <p>Test 1<br>example 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='5' class='itemy'>
    <div class='textcontainer'>
      <p>Test 1<br>example 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks @Tyler for additional informations.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @TylerRoper, I edited my answer !

Answer (score -3):

Simplest solution:

```
var addclass = 'color';
var $cols = $('.itemy').on('click hover', function() {
  $(this).addClass(addclass);
});
```

Best:

```
var addclass = 'color';
var $cols = $('.drinkDisplay').on('click hover', '.itemy', function() {
  $(this).addClass(addclass);
});
```

Access later by js:

```
var addclass = 'color';
var $cols = $('.drinkDisplay .itemy').filter(function( index ) {
  return $(this).hasClass(addclass);
})
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely "good" answers for a few reasons. For one, they're a game of "spot the difference". What did you change? Second, they don't often explain what OP has done incorrectly. *Why* did you change what you did? What did OP do wrong? All that aside, the only difference I see in your answer is that you've added a `hover` event, which doesn't really seem relevant at all to what OP's asked for.

Comment: 1.`Simplest Solution` -> just adds a class to elements when they are hovered and/or clicked. It won't remove that class ever. That's not what the OP is expecting. 2. `Best` does the same thing. 3. `Access later by js` -> why would you do a filter when you can selected them with CSS or with `$('.color') ` ? also you added `index` as argument, but never used it. Also, filter returns an array. You overcomplicate things

Comment: im sorry but i could not get it to work.is there anything else i should know about beside putting your code in a <script> tag?